# Не выводится картинка в Google Colab с помощью matplotlib. Что делать?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(street)
```

При компиляции выводит:

`<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7ff702094130>`

Answer (score 1):

Это старая известная проблема. Сам колаб имеет для неё решение.

```py
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

cv2_imshow(street)
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `plt.show()` после `plt.imshow(street)`. Это покажет картинку в `output` ячейки. Если код внутри функции, то добавьте `plt.show()` в конце функции. Если же картинка все еще не отображается, надо перезапустить ядро.
Также можно установить  библиотеку:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
!pip install -q -U matplotlib-gpu
```

или использовать функцию `display`:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(plt.imshow(street))
```

Answer (score 0):

В начале скрипта вставить строку:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Эта строка требовалась много лет назад, она давно уже не имеет никакого эффекта.

Comment: У меня вчера без нее не работало и удавалось только похожий ответ получить. Работал в google colab. Все остальные предложения не срабатывали